# swagger annotation content-type not set

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, swagger-ui, springfox

I have this spring rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/communications")
class CommunicationController(private val service: CommunicationService) {

    @ApiOperation(
        produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @GetMapping(
        consumes = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE], 
        produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE]
    )
    fun findAll(
        criterias: CommunicationCriterias, 
        page: Pageable
    ): List<CommunicationDTO> = service.findCommunications(criterias, page)

}
```

When I test this endpoint via the `swagger-ui` (springfox) interface, i got a `415: content type invalid` error. It seems that `content-type: application/json` is not set in the header.

What is missing ?

Comment: Which version of swagger you use?

Comment: I used `io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2` and `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2` but I finally removed de springfox dependencies and went with the classic swagger editor...

Comment: I have same issue at springfox-swagger2+springfox-swagger-ui v 2.9.2

Comment: Understand that this is an old post but somebody just posted an answer that worked for me, so posting here for reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078786/springfox-swagger-ui-not-sending-with-content-type-header

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to consume in HTTP GET request. I think you should remove the `consumes` from `@GetMapping` and `@ApiOperation`.

Comment: That makes sense since there is no json request payload. Thanks man. Had not thought of that