# Springfox swagger-ui not sending with content-type header

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have integrated `swagger` to my Spring Boot project using SpringFox build and it work for my GET API. However on my POST API which requires the request in `application/json` format, the swagger-ui doesn't set the header.

My Code:

```
@PostMapping(value="/login", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public WsResponse login(UserLoginRequest requestBody) throws Exception {

        validateAuthToken(requestBody.getId(), requestBody.getToken());

        return serviceWs.login(requestBody);
    }
```

The command generated from swagger-ui:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/login?token=2342343324&username=23434&password=123" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Note that the header "Content-Type" is not set and thus backend is giving an error when trying to call.

The issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933559/swagger-annotation-content-type-not-set) post but there's no resolution, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `application/json` within the braces:

[image: Swagger definition]

[image: Swagger UI]

**Note:** Works for me for springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui `v2.8.0`

Comment: The content type is omitted in springdoc's swagger UI (v1.4.3) requests, regardless of whether the braces are present.

Answer (score 0):

Add @RequestBody annotation in your post controller

e.g

```
 @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Student> add(@Valid @RequestBody Student student) {
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.add(student), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```